# Timouts continue to fire and execute after clearing timeouts and unmounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to create a bus animations from an array of coordinates, i'm using setTimeout to fire function to move marker to next coordinate, but i need to stop execution when user chooses another station from parent component, so when user clicks in another station, i firstly set routes to Null and fetch new coordinates for the buses of this particular station, which represents routes in the code below

The problem :
functions continue firing even after clearing timeouts and unmounting component.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong
here is my code

Bus marker component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-yamap';
import { BusView } from '../../../../../../components/transport/bus-view';
import { Route } from '../../../../../../modules/transport/types/Route';
import { Station } from 'modules/transport/types/Station';

interface Props {
  route: Route;
  visible: boolean;
  selectedStation: Station | null;
  routes: Route[];
}

export const BusMarker = React.memo(function BusMarker(props: Props) {
  const name = props.route?.bus_number?.replace(/\D/g, '');
  const busRef = React.useRef<Marker>(null);
  const [timeouts, setTimeOuts] = React.useState<NodeJS.Timeout[]>([]);
  let timerRef = React.createRef();
  
const animateMarker = React.useCallback(() => {
    const current = props?.route.current_location ?? 0;
    let prevTimeOuts: NodeJS.Timeout[] = [];
    console.log('animation start for marker', 
    props.route.bus_number, 'from position :', 
    current);

    props?.route?.route?.slice(current + 1)?.forEach((bus, index) => {
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('animateMarker', props.route.bus_number, 'to position index:', index);
        busRef?.current?.animatedMoveTo(
          {
            lat: bus.lat,
            lon: bus.lon,
          },
          1000 * props.route.average_second_per_coordinate,
        );
      }, index * 1000 * props.route.average_second_per_coordinate);
      prevTimeOuts = [...prevTimeOuts, timerRef.current];
    });
    setTimeOuts(prevTimeOuts);
  }, [props.selectedStation]);

  const clearAllTimeouts = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('clearAllTimeouts');
    timeouts.forEach(timeout => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    });
    setTimeOuts([]);
  }, [timeouts]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    animateMarker();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearAllTimeouts();
    };
  }, [props.selectedStation, props.routes]);

  return (
    props.route?.route?.[0] && (
      <Marker
        visible={props.visible}
        scale={1}
        ref={busRef}
        key={props.route.bus_number}
        point={{
          lat: props.route?.route[props.route.current_location ?? 0].lat,
          lon: props.route?.route[props.route.current_location ?? 0].lon,
        }}
        children={<BusView name={name} type={props.route?.tt_id} />}
      />
    )
  );
});
```

and this is the parent component :

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    getRoutes(); // fetch new coordinates for buses of selected station
  }, [selectedStation]);

const handleChangeStation = (station: Station) => {
    setRoutes(() => null);
    setSelectedStation(() => station);
  };

{routes?.[0] &&
   routes.map((route, index) => (
      <BusMarker 
         key={index} 
         route={route} 
         visible={showBuses} 
         selectedStation={selectedStation} 
         routes={routes} 
      />
 ))} // render buses on map
```

Comment: What is the point of `timerRef` if you are keeping your (multple!) timer ids in an array?

Comment: I tried with ref or without it and i'm having the same result, i learned that i should save the reference of the timeout cause every time component rerenders hes is creating new one

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to use a ref instead of a state here, but you need to store **all** your timeout ids that you're creating in that `forEach` loop in there. Not just the last one.

Comment: ```const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('animateMarker', props.route.bus_number, 'to position index:', index);
        busRef?.current?.animatedMoveTo(
          {
            lat: bus.lat,
            lon: bus.lon,
          },
          1000 * props.route.average_second_per_coordinate,
        );
      }, index * 1000 * props.route.average_second_per_coordinate);
      prevTimeOuts = [...prevTimeOuts, timerId];
    });
    setTimeOuts(prevTimeOuts);```this without ref

Comment: but the result is the same this is not stopping the execution

Comment: As I said, remove the `timeouts` state. Use `timersRef.current = prevTimeouts` instead of `setTimeOuts(prevTimeOuts);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
 return () => {
   clearAllTimeouts();
 };
}, [props.selectedStation, props.routes]);
```

Changing the array of timeouts does not cause the effect from above to change which actually clears the timeouts (note: clearAllTimeouts is using the "old" array).
Therefore timeouts which are stored in setTimeOuts without changing ether selectedStation or routes the new timeouts are never cancelled.

In general you can simplify your code a lot and putting all animation consern related code into one useEffect:

```js
export const BusMarker = React.memo(function BusMarker(props: Props) {
    const name = props.route?.bus_number?.replace(/\D/g, '');
    const busRef = React.useRef<Marker>(null);

    const currentRoute = props.route;
    const currentLocation = props.route.current_location ?? 0;
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!currentRoute || !currentRoute.route || currentRoute.route.length === 0) {
            /* No route to animate*/
            return;
        }

        console.log('animation start for marker', props.route.bus_number, 'from position :', currentLocation);
        const timeouts = currentRoute.route.slice(currentLocation + 1).map((bus, index) => {
            return setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('animateMarker', currentRoute.bus_number, 'to position index:', index);
                busRef.current?.animatedMoveTo(
                    {
                        lat: bus.lat,
                        lon: bus.lon,
                    },
                    1000 * currentRoute.average_second_per_coordinate,
                );
            }, index * 1000 * currentRoute.average_second_per_coordinate);
        });

        return () => {
            /* Cleanup all timeouts when animation parameters changed or on unmount. */
            for (const timeout of timeouts) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        };
    }, [currentRoute, props.selectedStation, currentLocation]);
    /* Does props.selectedStation equal currentLocation or why did selectedStation has been a dependency beforehand? */

    return (
        props.route?.route?.[0] && (
            <Marker
                visible={props.visible}
                scale={1}
                ref={busRef}
                key={props.route.bus_number}
                point={{
                    lat: props.route?.route[props.route.current_location ?? 0].lat,
                    lon: props.route?.route[props.route.current_location ?? 0].lon,
                }}
                children={<BusView name={name} type={props.route?.tt_id} />}
            />
        )
    );
});
```

I'd recommand putting any dependencies which causes the animation to change into the React.useEffect dependency array.
Please note that I haven't tested this code so there might be some typos or I overlooked something.

Comment: can i replace map with forEach ?

Comment: No, since mat returns the timeout id which then is stored as "timeouts". You could instead declare the array as const timeouts  = [], use a forEach and push the timeout id into timeouts.